# Smallest secure web server to simply run script

Tags: tomcat, webserver, tomcat7

Tomcat occasionally crashes (freezes).  So I simply ssh into the server and restart tomcat, sometimes forcibly.  I want to be able to do this from a simple **Webapp** I can access over my phone if needed or my monitoring **App** can access.

So what's the smallest memory-footprint web server that can execute a script which will restart tomcat?  This other web server will clearly need to be secure as I'll be executing critical scripts with it.

***NOTE***:

I want a web server in *addition* to tomcat, not to replace it.  This new small web server does not have to run or be based on Java, it just needs to run some kind of script that will restart tomcat.

Comment: I guess Jetty's footprint is the smallest one available (or the internal web server shipped with JDK). I'd rather try to find out why tomcat (the application) occasionally crashes... opening a web server for systems administration to the outside world really is a security nightmare. What's the issue using SSH?

Comment: The issue using SSH is that no monitoring service has an SSH mechanism to try to recover failed servers, nor am I sure I want that.  Plus I want an easier time restarting things than SSH where I can do so through my phone.

Comment: Update: it's not 1999 anymore. Tomcat just doesn't randomly crashes without reason. Your effort would be better spent on figuring out what's wrong with your application or Tomcat configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx is a very lightweight web server that will fit the bill. Anyway, I would just automate it as a watchdog script that periodically tests tomcat status and restarts when needed.